# How to set the default file permissions on ALL newly created files in linux

Tags: linux, security, permissions

My question is similar to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228534/linux-default-file-permission

but there is no scp/ftp client involved and that question looks abandoned. Simply put: I want to be able to, at some global level decree that all newly created files will never have world writable permissions (0775).

I tried putting a umask 02 in /etc/profile then in my bash_profile but it only works for scripts or new files that I create in a shell. It doesn't work for files that another binary creates. Is there anyway to have all new files that are created?

Comment: It's possible you may be able to do what you want by modifying the mount - either giving it a umask in /etc/fstab (umask=xxxx in the options section, but this is not available for ext*) or by chmod-ing the mountpoint.

Comment: Good description here: http://superuser.com/questions/318833/how-do-you-apply-umask-settings-to-an-account-that-doesnt-log-in

Answer (score 1):

[umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) is what you want...

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the `UMASK` setting in the `/etc/login.defs` file.

Comment: The description in my /etc/login.defs says: `Umask which is used be useradd and newusers for creating new home directories.` Doesn't sound like a global level decree for all services/ processes.